# Is it possible to find all primary keys that have system generated names in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know of a couple of different ways to find all primary keys in the db, but is it possible to filter the results, so that it only show primary keys that have system generated names? None of the attributes returned by these queries seem relevant, so I am guessing I'll have to join another table or call a function, but I can't find anything relevant.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type_desc = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'

SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

The reason I want to show these results is so that I can find and rename these constraints in a large database.

Edit:
By system generated names I mean primary keys that have been created by just adding `PRIMARY KEY` behind the column name in the table definition, so that it gets a name like: PK__Countrie__5D9B0D2D28F35AE2

Comment: Why would the system bother to *store* the fact that it was forced to generate the name? That particular fact was only relevant *whilst* the constraint was being created. After that point, such constraints are indistinguishable from any other constraint. Best you can probably do is pattern matching against the names, assuming you don't also give names to your constraints that look like the system generated ones.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: some DBMS _do_ store the information whether or not the constraint name was generated. So it's not unreasonable to ask I think

Comment: The correct term is "system generated name" not "default name", I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way would be this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.key_constraints
WHERE type = 'PK'
  AND is_system_named = 1
```

Just check the `is_system_named` property in the `sys.key_constraints` view

Answer (score 1):

***An auto-generated PK seems to contain 16 hexadecimal digits in its name***.
So I would use this query and then still manually check the results from it. Why check them manually? Because maybe the above statement may be just something undocumented, and may not apply in future versions of SQL Server.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type_desc = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
and
name like '%[A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9][A-F0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest I came up with is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'PK__' + left(TABLE_NAME, 8) +'__[A-Z|0-9]%'
```